# Qt QScrollArea autoscroll

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having problems with QLabel and QScrollArea. I'm trying to make QScrollArea to scroll automatically, but can't find any information about it..

Firstly, I'm using QLabel inside QScrollArea, then QLineEdit outside from QScrollArea. When I type text in QLineEdit, it writes to QLabel and the new line. Whenever it reaches to end of area, QScrollArea doesn't scroll automatically.. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use QLineEdit itself instead of Qlabel(if u are using only text)?, so that you dont have to use QScrollArea also.

[edit]
What if you set the verticalSlider position to Label->height()

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed() 
{ 
  ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + ui->lineEdit->text() + "\n"); 

  ui->ScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(label->height())

}
```

Comment: Nope, cause my project requires QLabel really much.

Comment: Set the slider position to label height:- ScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(label->height())or you can do ui->ScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderDown(true)

Comment: only ScrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setSliderPosition(label->height()) worked for me, thank you really much!

Comment: By the way, can you point me in which header is located setSliderPosition? I'm including QAbstractSlider but it doesn't work.

Comment: Its included in QAbstractSlider only ,I don't know why it is not working. Is that showing any error?.Try including QScrollBar also, dont know whether this will fix

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23790/
Without to see your code that is difficult to be more precise ...

[EDITED] Try this:

```
void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed() 
{ 
  ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + ui->lineEdit->text() + "\n"); 

  ui->lineEdit->moveCursor (QTextCursor::Start) ;
  ui->lineEdit->ensureCursorVisible() ;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't help.

Take a look here:

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + ui->lineEdit->text() + "\n");
    ui->lineEdit->clear();
}

I'm not using code at all, instead, I'm doing in UI editor. QScrollArea already QLabel widget inside it, but it doesn't automatically scroll.

Comment: Try this: ui->lineEdit->moveCursor (QTextCursor::Start) ;
  ui->lineEdit->ensureCursorVisible() ;

Comment: has no member of "moveCursor" :/ also included the QTextCursor header.